# Moving a file in nextcloud via webDAV API fails

Tags: curl, webdav, nextcloud

I am trying to run a CURL command from a linux command line that is supposed to move a file to a different folder, according to this manual: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/basic.html#copying-files-and-folders-rfc4918

First I created the folder:

`curl 'https://example.com/remote.php/dav/files/user/recording/2023/02/18' --user 'user:password' --request MKCOL`

This works fine.

Then I am trying to move a file to this folder:

`curl 'https://example.com/remote.php/dav/files/user/recording/2023-02-18 18-24-52.mp4' --user 'user:password' --request MOVE -H 'Destination:https://example.com/remote.php/dav/files/user/recording/2023/02/18/'`

However, on this I am getting a 400 error with "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.". I tried several different sequences in the command (not sure if it matters), short (-X) and long (--request) flags and dropping the last / on the target directory but I could not figure out.

I checked the logfile while having it on DEBUG mode but while the MKCOL call leaves it's traces there, there is no logfile content AT ALL regarding the MOVE request. There lis a line in the apache log, but just stating this:

```
[02/Aug/2023:16:54:26 +0800] "MOVE /remote.php/dav/files/user/recording/2023-02-18 18-24-52.mp4" 400 226
```

Comment: It appears you have a space character in your request URI, no?

Comment: Isn't that covered with the quotes? But thanks for the suggestion, will try if that's an issue.

Comment: just tried it, it works now. Thanks! If you want to post this as the answer, please go ahead. the solution is to replace spaces with %20.